# Android Login Activity not fetching from database

Tags: java, android, json, import

So from a previous question I have added some new dependencies to my Gradle properties to allow HttpGetRequest commands etc. However now there are further errors in my code which I presume mean that the new dependency I have added is not compatible with the JSON statements. Can you please have a look through and see whether it is these dependencies that have broken my code?

Gradle Dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

And my LoginActivity code:

```
package com.example.george.youdecide;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.message.BasicNameValuePair;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    // Initializing variables
    private EditText user, pass;
    private ImageView mSubmit, mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    //Localhost URL stuff goes here
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://172.18.5.215/webservice/login.php";

    //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //setup input fields
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameLogin);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);

        //setup buttons
        mSubmit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        //register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // determine which button was pressed:
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.loginButton:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
                break;
            //case R.id.register:
              //  Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
                //startActivity(i);
               // break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            //user.getText method error here
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                //Parameter errors here
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * Get rid of progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

After changing the dependencies I still get errors with these parts of the code.

```
int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
```

and here

```
Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
android {
    ...
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
```

Instead of:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
```

Comment: Thanks, however these statements below are still producing errors, any ideas? ' int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {'